# Vagrant, launching command in ssh with environment variables

Tags: bash, yii, ssh, vagrant

I have a vagrantbox with a LAMP stack and YiiFramework.
I need to run some commands that rely on environment variables that I set provisioning the box in the .bashrc (.profile has the same behavior though).
The problem is that I want to launch them using ssh, but everything I tried is not working. For example:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t '[path]/./yiic command action'
```

Tells me that I didn't set the env variables.
Even:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'printenv MYSQL_HOST'
```

Has this output:

```
rmessineo:~ rmessineo$ switebox ssh -- -t 'printenv MYSQL_HOST'
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
rmessineo:~ rmessineo$
```

But of course if I login in and to the same:

```
rmessineo:~ rmessineo$ vagrant ssh

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Feb 24 11:02:05 2016 from 10.0.2.2

vagrant@debian-jessie:~$ printenv MYSQL_HOST
127.0.0.1
vagrant@debian-jessie:~$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following in my `.profile` file in the VM

```
export MY_VAR="hello fred"
```

Then I am able to get the value of the new variable by running

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ vagrant ssh -- -t 'source ~/.profile && printenv MY_VAR'
hello fred
Connection to 192.168.6.120 closed.
```

Comment: Same problem: `rmessineo:vagrantBox rmessineo$ vagrant ssh -c "source .profile && printenv MYSQL_HOST"
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
rmessineo:vagrantBox rmessineo$ `

Comment: I combined your run with mine and it works `vagrant ssh -- -t 'source ~/.profile && printenv MY_VAR'` (I have created a MY_VAR in my case to test) it prints MY_VAR value

Comment: I was using .bashr... i tried using .profile and I made it work! Thank you @Frédéric!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the vagrant instance starts with port `2222`, then you can run the command:

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1 'printenv MYSQL_HOST'
```

password is `vagrant`, then you should get the result.

Update the port depend the real vagrant instance.

Comment: Unfortunately the output is the following:

     rmessineo:~ rmessineo$ ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1 'printenv MYSQL_HOST'  
     vagrant@127.0.0.1's password: 
     rmessineo:~ rmessineo$`
(and i don't want to insert the password)